# Where Do I Go To Find All The ScriptContexts Feilds and Functions?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, documentation

Hi im getting lost in the documentation, I have found some things I was looking for but am failing to find the info and functions for script contents. Im using this link https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/ where should I look in here the docs are pretty long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here it is: https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/Plutus-V1-Ledger-Contexts.html

## a little hint to use the docs:

usually when I'm searching for some module I press `Ctrl`+`F` (for "find") and type for some module I'm looking for.

in this case by going to https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/ I just pressed `Ctrl`+`F` and searched for "Context"

### pro tip

on modules-specific pages you can use the same trick with functions type signature

as an example say you are searching for a function that gives you back the total value spent but you don't remember the name

just press `Ctrl`+`F` and search for something like `-> value`

> the search is NOT case sensitive

to quickly find all the functions that do return `Value`s

Comment: Yeah I asked because I got something weird using ctrl F but that's for another question

Comment: Try searching with just `S`